# How to save cloud space in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am planning to start a small photo/video sharing app that self-destruct after a while (like Snapchat) using Firebase.

The question is: Since Firebase has storage limitations and charges surplus for certain things, is it possible to use a cron job to delete expired files and save space? Or will I be charged anyway?

Thanks in advance, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only be charged for files that are being stored in your Storage bucket. So if you remove files, you will no longer be charged for the space those files took going forward. Cleaning up unneeded data is a great way to reduce the cost of your solution.

It seems you can set an auto-delete policy on your Cloud Storage bucket through its [object lifecycle management feature](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle), but I'll admit I've never used that myself.

When I've needed to periodically clean up, I've [run a scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that then used the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) to remove the outdated files.